# What is the difference between UML 2.1.2 and UML 2.2

Tags: uml, modeling

I am evaluating a tool which says that it supports UML 2.2. However if I search on internet, I can't find what incremental change has occured between two version.

And yes, I tried to go through OMG documents, but those are too dense to read. Is there a simple explanation anywhere?

Comment: It's UML. By definition, neither the explanation, nor anything else about it is simple.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there's a clear overview of the changes in 2.2. There's a UML 2.2 specification document with change bars: it marks the changed sections as opposed to version 2.1.2. It's really the best way to view those changes - again, there's no real overview, at least none that I could find. You can view the document (PDF) [here](http://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/apps/doc?formal/09-02-03.pdf).

I've skimmed the document a bit. They're mostly minor changes. Some of the changes I came across you can quickly find in:

- 8.3 (Class Descriptions)
- 8.3.2 (ComponentRealization)
- 10.2 (Deployments - Abstract Syntax)
- 11.2 (Abstract Syntax)
- 11.3.12 (ClearStructuralFeatureAction)
- 11.3.19 (InputPin)
- 11.3.33 (ReadLinkAction)
- 11.3.47 (StartObjectBehaviorAction)
- 11.3.55 (WriteStructuralFeatureAction)
- 15.2 (State Machines - Abstract syntax)

Comment: Thank you, you saved me a lot of time.

Comment: You're welcome. Note though, that the list is not complete. However, with the change bars, it is not too hard to quickly view what sections have changed. Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what your reference level of UML is, but [the UML 2.2 specifications with change bars](http://www.omg.org/technology/documents/formal/uml.htm) shows you all the changes. It just takes time page turning. It's perhaps easier to read through [the RTF Report for revision 2.2](http://www.omg.org/cgi-bin/doc?ptc/2008-06-03).